# Storing Image using node after uploading using angular

Tags: javascript, node.js, angularjs, http

I am creating a web app using mean stack where any user can upload an image and it would be stored in the mongo db or in a folder in the server system.
I am using the [angular-file-upload](https://github.com/danialfarid/angular-file-upload) for uploading the image. The problem comes in the nodejs part where when i try to print the req.body it is showing an empty object.

HTMl code: `<input type="file" ng-file-select="onFileSelect($files)" >`

Angular code:

```
$scope.onFileSelect = function($files) {
        for (var i = 0; i < $files.length; i++) {
          var file = $files[i];
          console.log(file);
          $scope.upload = $upload.upload({
            url: '/imagePost/'+Global.user._id, 
             method: 'POST' ,

            data: {myObj: 'image'},
            file: file, 
          }).progress(function(evt) {
            console.log('percent: ' + parseInt(100.0 * evt.loaded / evt.total));
          }).success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
            console.log('success');
          });
          }

      };
```

Node code:

```
app.post('/imagePost/:userid',function(req,res){

 console.log('I came here');
 console.log(req.body);
 res.send('');
});
```

Here i just try to print the requestbody but i get an empty object. I included all the dependencies.
If this doesnt work what I feel doing is reading the image and sending it in request and creating a new image in the node code which can be later stored in a folder.
But why am I not getting any object in request body. Please help me..

Comment: It won't be in `req.body`, it'll be in `req.files`.

Comment: even i tried req.files and in this case I got undefined

Comment: Can you add the part of express where you've added your dependencies please (`app.use()`).

Comment: app.use(expressValidator());
    app.use(bodyParser());
    app.use(methodOverride());
    app.use(cookieParser());

Comment: is it a better idea to read the image and send the data via http and create a new image in node..?

Answer (score 1):

I think you are using Express v4.x

if yes, you get empty object in **req.body**, because starting from Express 4, bodyParser is deprecated and replaced with body-parser.

Read about the migration from v3 to v4 
[here](https://github.com/senchalabs/connect#middleware)

- body-parser

It only support **urlencoded** and **json**, **multipart** is no longer supported, if you want to use multipart, you need to add it seperately

You need **multipart** which used to be supported by **bodyParser**, for receiving files from your client side

You can either use any of the below;

1. busboy (recommended because it is fast)
2. multiparty
3. mutler (wrapper for busboy, make your life easier coding
4. formidable

Comment: thanx for ur answer I already solved the problem using mutler and its really easier to code...I have a doubt is there a way to send both data and files in a single http post...? without using angular-file-upload

Comment: you need to use angular-file-upload or any custom directive, because AngularJS doesnt support file uploade, you can try send a JSON in the data, example: data: {myObj: 'image', data: 'yourData'}